# Accessing files with relative filepath inside built jar java

Tags: java, file, path

I have a project which uses relative file paths to access resources. While the project is run in IDE, the path looks like.

```
\\src\\musicTest\\Track4O.mp3
```

When the project is built into a jar file, this no longer works. Upon opening the jar file, I noticed that the file structure looked like

```
musicTest.jar\\musicTest\\Track4O.mp3
```

In both cases, the class attempting to load the resource was in the same location as the mp3. 
If anyone has a solution for either: maintaining the file path so that the build will run as intended or: solving the relative file path problem, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your relative code ?

Comment: A .jar entry is not a separate file, so you cannot use FileInputStream to read it.  Use `MusicTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/musicTest/Track4O.mp3")` instead.  The argument is a relative URL, not a file name, so it must use `/` as a directory separator on all platforms.